# Setup ag-grid in Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to set up **ag-grid** my already running Angular project but I am unable to get the dependencies. In our project we have ag-grid 8.2.0 version available. We do not have ag-grid-angular or any other dependency. To get ag-grid support for Angular, do we need to get other dependencies as well? How can I set up the ag-grid to work in my project?

U**PDATE 1:** As mentioned in the link, we can use:
'ag-grid-angular' : 'node_modules/ag-grid-angular',
        'ag-grid' : 'node_modules/ag-grid',
        'ag-grid-enterprise' : 'node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise'
    },
    packages: {
        'ag-grid-angular': {
            defaultExtension: "js"
        },
        'ag-grid': {
            defaultExtension: "js"
        },
        'ag-grid-enterprise': {
            defaultExtension: "js"
        }
        ...other packages

**but in our project we have only ag-grid v8.2.0 available and not ag-grid-angular.** So I am able to put 'ag-grid': {
            defaultExtension: "js"
        }, only in my system.config file and package.json.

Is ag-grid-angular also required for ag-grid to run in angular 2 How can I get the same as we cannot access npm as well.

Comment: here is their [guide](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0) if after you have gone through their guide you still have problems, then post specifically what you have tried and what errors are being thrown and your set up so that we may better help to diagnose the issue

Comment: ag-grid-angular was a name change brought about on google request. You should try and keep as up to date as possible. The instructions for installing on the support site are very good and also should be followed before dropping questions of this nature..

Answer (score 2):

**add dependencies in package.json :**

```
"ag-grid-angular": "^20.2.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^20.2.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.2.0",
"@ag-grid-community/all-modules": "^22.0.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^22.0.0",
```

**add AgGridModule in your Module:**

```
AgGridModule.withComponents([])
import {AgGridModule} from 'ag-grid-angular';

add style for theme ag grid in style.scss from node-module
```

**add below code in app.component.ts**

```
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
```

Answer (score 1):

1. create angular project
2. add ag-grid dependencies
3. add ag-grid module dependecy in AppModule
4. import ag-grid styles in styles.scss
5. use ag-grid-angular component to render ag-grid

Below url may helps you.
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-getting-started/

Comment: Couldn't have said it better. I've been coding since the wheel was invented but new to Angular and ag-grid. I've hosed a few projects and this is exactly how I resolved it. 1) Start clean with a project that works...and 2) Figure out why that app works and yours doesn't. Their getting started guide is *very* good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both `ag-grid` and `ag-grid-angular` are required. `ag-grid-angular` (previously `ag-grid-ng2`) is the Angular wrapper for the Ag-Grid codebase.

Comment: Is ag-grid-angular free or chargeable? Also, even after including ag-grid and having ag-grid in node modules, I could not find ag-grid/main as described in various examples?

Comment: As stated in their docs, `enterprise` features are the only paid features. You need a licence key to use them. I would suggest looking at their repo first: https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-angular-example

Answer (score 0):

in your systemjs.config.js declare the path to ag-grid's main file:

```
     'ag-grid': {
        main: 'main.js'
     },
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ag-grid-angular is required for ag-grid to run in angular 2. You need to include ag-grid-angular in your package.json file to get the dependencies. You can use webpack for bundling.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "ag-grid": "^13.3.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^13.3.0"
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import {AgGridModule} from "ag-grid-angular";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule, // <-- import the FormsModule before binding with [(ngModel)]
        AgGridModule.withComponents([
            ProficiencyCellRenderer
        ])
    ],
})
```